# Regex for removing punctuation but ignoring forward slash?

Tags: c#, regex, forward, slash

So I'm building a small parser in C# where a user can enter names. Now these names can be on threeformats:

```
"name" OR "name / name" OR "name-name"
```

The user might write an input string with different punctuation such as `name?` or `name.` To remove these I got a regex going, looks like this:

```
   var expression = "name / name";
   var regexPunctuation = new Regex(@"[^-\w\s]");
   expression = regexPunctuation.Replace(expression, string.Empty);
```

My regex works for single names and names with a `-` in between but not names that have a forward slash. If the user inputs `name / name` the result is just `name name`. How can I change my regex so that it ignores forward slash so that the result is `name / name`? Take note of the extra spaces between the `name / name`.

Comment: did you try to add a slash to your ignore pattern? `new Regex(@"[^-\w\s/]");`

Comment: Split the string first, and process each of the 2 substrings, then join back. If there is no `/`, just process the only `name` part.

Comment: What do the extra spaces have to do with the problem?  You say "take note", but as far as I can see they have nothing to do with the problem.  If they are relevant, please explain with detail.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
new Regex(@"[^-/\w\s]")
```

Comment: Tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: http://imgur.com/C468GZ6 Maybe you have something wrong in another part of program?

Comment: This works for me too, using the code snippet from the question but with the extra slash in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `/` like this: `new Regex(@"[^-\/\w\s]")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexPunctuation = new Regex(@"[^-\/\w\s]");
```

Comment: There's no need to escape a forward slash.  / is not a regex meta character.